# Windows Runtime / Universal Apps Package Dependencies

Tags: windows, windows-runtime, win-universal-app

I am trying to find more information on this property:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.applicationmodel.package.dependencies.aspx

(As you can see, the documentation is not very thorough.)

There is a downloadable package that claims to demonstrate this property in its third sample here:
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Package-sample-46e239fa

However, when I run this sample and click the Dependencies button provided in the sample, the number it returns is 0.  Also, inspecting this property at runtime reveals that it is an empty collection as well.

It would be great if someone could offer some insight/assistance around this property, and also explain why it does not seem to be working with the code sample outlined above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dependencies are things like the Visual C++ libraries. A pure managed app won't have any dependencies, but a native app (or a managed app with a native component) will have a dependency. I believe a WWA app will have a dependency as well for the WinJS library.

Here is the Immediate window output from a managed app with a C++ WinRT component:

```
Package.Current.Dependencies[0].Id.FullName
"Microsoft.VCLibs.120.00.Phone.Debug_12.0.30113.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe"
```

Comment: What about if you have a managed WinRT component in the project? Shouldn't they be treated the same as a native WinRT component?

Comment: Wow.  Thank you for your reply, Peter.  This does seem misleading and confusing.  Are you in effect saying that the C# version of the sample provided in the link above should not have a "Dependencies" sample, since it really doesn't apply to it?  And also, it should really be called "Native Dependencies" to be more accurate?

Comment: The samples tend to be 1:1 with each other for consistency across languages, but in this case the managed sample shows something not particularly interesting. It isn't correct to say "Native Dependencies" because WinJS is not native. In the future there could be other dependencies, too, there just aren't many yet.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood which part was the dependency. Thanks.

Comment: @CÅdahl I am glad I am not the only one struggling with this.  @ Peter (it won't let me mention two people in posts??), thank you for your assistance and insight!